# How to implement functional parallel-map in c?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, functional-programming, array-map, purely-functional

A functional map is a function that applies a callback function to each element in an array and returns a list of callback return values. For example, in pseudocode, `map(["hello", "world"], fn(x) => x + " meow")` would return `["hello meow", "world meow"]`

Since function pointers can be passed as parameters in C, it is possible to implement a functional map like below:

```c
void** fp_map(void** array, size_t len, void* (*execute)(void*))
{
    // Allocate memory for return items
    void** returns = malloc(sizeof(void*) * len);
    if (returns == NULL) err(42, "Malloc failed, buy more ram");

    // Map values
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        returns[i] = execute(array[i]);

    return returns;
}
```

If I write the following anonymous function in my main method, it would map `["hello", "world"]` to `["hello meow", "world meow"]`:

```c
int main() {
    char* arr[] = {"hello", "world"};

    char** arr2 = fp_map((void**) arr, 2, ({ void* _func_ (void* x) {
        char* buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(x) + 7));
        strcpy(buf, x);
        strcat(buf, " meow");
        return buf;
    }; _func_; }));

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", arr2[i]);
}
```

Now, I want to implement a **parallel map** to speed things up. Since this is purely functional, calls to the callback function with the same parameters would return the same return values. How can I use multithreading so that each call to `execute()` runs on a different thread, but still have the results return in an ordered array?

Comment: *How can I use multithreading so that each call to `execute()` runs on a different thread, but still have the results return in an ordered array?*  Offhand, I don't think that'd be useful under those constraints because you're waiting for the return value for each call to `execute()`.  You'd need something more complex that involves waiting on the parallel threads.

Comment: OT: `_func_` is confusingly close to [standard C's `__func__`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.2.2p1).

Comment: Have you tried OpenMP? It allows trivial transformation of for loops to parallel loops.

Comment: In OpenMP, this can be done using `#pragma omp parallel for`. Note that you need to add the flag `-fopenmp` in the build command (and the link one). Note that heap allocations tends not to scale so it is better to avoid it in multithreaded codes. Stack allocation scale perfectly so it is better to use it when it is possible.

Comment: `in c?` Your code is not C. `({` is a GNU extension. Accessing `char *` via a `void **` is also technically invalid. And your code is leaking memory `How can I use multithreading` Soo, do you know how to create a thread, for starters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written the following code, in which I create a context for the thread, then for every calculation I spawn a separate thread. Join all the threads and return the value.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <threads.h>

#define ERRORON(expr) \
    do { \
        if (expr) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %s\n", #expr); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

#define ARRLEN(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(*x))

struct mythread_context {
    void **returns;
    void *(*execute)(void *);
    void **array;
    size_t i;
};

int mythread(void *arg) {
    const struct mythread_context *ctx = arg;
    // Execute the stuff to execute.
    ctx->returns[ctx->i] = ctx->execute(ctx->array[ctx->i]);
    return 0;
}

void **fp_map(void **array, size_t len, void *(*execute)(void *)) {
    // Allocate memory for return items
    void **returns = malloc(sizeof(*returns) * len);
    ERRORON(!returns);
    // Allocate memory for threads and contextes.
    thrd_t *threads = malloc(sizeof(*threads) * len);
    ERRORON(!threads);
    struct mythread_context *ctxs = malloc(sizeof(*ctxs) * len);
    ERRORON(!ctxs);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        const struct mythread_context thisctx = {
            .returns = returns,
            .execute = execute,
            .array = array,
            .i = i,
        };
        ctxs[i] = thisctx;
        // Start a thread for every returns, execute and array index.
        int ret = thrd_create(&threads[i], mythread, &ctxs[i]);
        ERRORON(ret != thrd_success);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        // Join all threads. They will assing to returns separately concurrently.
        int ret = thrd_join(threads[i], NULL);
        ERRORON(ret != thrd_success);
    }
    free(threads);
    free(ctxs);
    return returns;
}

void *appnend_to_char(void *x) {
    char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(x) + 7));
    strcpy(buf, x);
    strcat(buf, " meow");
    return buf;
}

int main() {
    const char *arr[] = {"hello", "world"};
    char **arr2 = (char **)fp_map((void **)arr, ARRLEN(arr), appnend_to_char);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRLEN(arr); ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", arr2[i]);
    }
    // free memory
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRLEN(arr); ++i) {
        free(arr2[i]);
    }
    free(arr2);
}
```

Alternatively, you can just seamlessly integrate with OpenMP, with just:

```
void **fp_map(void **array, size_t len, void *(*execute)(void *)) {
    void **returns = malloc(sizeof(*returns) * len);
    ERRORON(!returns);
    size_t i;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        returns[i] = execute(array[i]);
    }
    return returns;
}
```

Notes:

- `({` is a GCC extension, *not* part of C language. There are no lambdas or anonymous functions in C programming langauge.
- I am not sure if C11 threads.h should be used or rather POSIX pthreads should be preferred. The interface is very similar.
- The context is rather big, it could be optimized. The count of `malloc` coudl also be optimized.